# Why do I see changes in Git Status and not in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

In Git, I run `git status` and I have about 20 modified files in red.

In Visual Studio 2012 using the new Visual Studio Tools for Git, I see no changes.

Why?

Comment: Are there any actual changes?  Or is it whitespace freaking out one of your versions of git?

Comment: I don't know. I can't tell unless they show up in VS so I can use the diff tool.

Comment: Well, clearly VS thinks there aren't changes.  I'm asking about what your other git tool thinks changed.

Comment: Actually, you might be right. I remembered I have Git GUI or something installed and that shows the files but the right-hand pane, which probably is supposed to show the delta, is empty for every file.

Comment: You ran `git status` at a command line somewhere right?  What does `git diff` say there?  I don't know what Git GUI has to do with anything...

Comment: Ah okay (I can't use Git command line) I get the same note about LF replaced by CRLF under each file. Do you want to add a proper answer and collect some points, Carl?

Comment: Sure, will do.  One moment...  I don't understand how you ran `git status` if you don't have a command line.

Comment: I have the command line, I'm just inept with it so diffing and stuff is beyond me. I tried reading the documentation many times. There's some incompatibility between me and Git that doesn't exist in other products.

Comment: It's definitely a learning curve, but worth it IMHO.  I think the most telling thing is that nobody who switches from a traditional VCS to git ever wants to go back.

Comment: I found this very helpful in learning git: http://gitimmersion.com/index.html.  Also, SourceTree is pretty slick, too.

Comment: @CarlNorum We switched to Git 6 months ago. It's caused no end of problems for everyone except the Mac devs. I loath it with every fibre in my being and I'd move to TFS in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess (as discussed in the comments above) is that you have different whitespace handling configurations in the two different git programs you're running.  You'll need to figure out which one is right and fix the other one to match.